# Can I build a dynamic Web3 site using IPFS?

Tags: django, web3js, ipfs, pinata, fleek

This is more of a general question. I would like to connect a dynamic site to a Web3 domain (.x) I have read that only static builds are possible using the IPFS protocol and Web3 platforms (such as Pinata, Fleek etc.).

Just digging into Web3 development further. Appreciate any clarity, thoughts or pointers.

And when I say dynamic, I mean full backend and frontend stack capabilities using frameworks such as Django.